# react-router - component not updating data on initial view

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When navigating through my application the data served as props are not updating as expected. However, if I reload the page, the data updates as expected.

I'm not sure why this is? I don't have this issue on other pages within my application? Would a solution be to force reload the page?

Here is my react-router code:

```
/* Packages */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Route, Router, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

/* Import Data */
import store from './store'

/* Containers */
import App from './js/containers/App';
import Home from './js/containers/Home';
import HowWeDoIt from './js/containers/HowWeDoIt';
import AdProducts from './js/containers/AdProducts';
import AdProduct from './js/containers/AdProduct';
import News from './js/containers/News';
import Showcase from './js/containers/Showcase';

/* Styles */
import './index.css';

const app = document.getElementById('app');
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={App} history={history}>
                <Route path="approach" component={HowWeDoIt} history={history} />
                <Route path="products" component={AdProducts} history={history} />
                <Route path="products/:product" component={AdProduct} history={history} />
                <Route path="news" component={News} history={history} />
                <Route path="showcase" component={Showcase} history={history} />
                <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>, 
app);
```

Comment: Please provide more info on how you are fetching the info and sending it to the component in question. A barebones representation of the issue would help.

Comment: @RicardoLopes Sorry Ricardo - just updated the question with code

Comment: But where are you actually calling `fetchHomeData()`?

Comment: Ah just updated now @RicardoLopes

Comment: Which router you are using ? If it is "react-router-dom" , then you need to pass the "BrowserHistory" to each component for redirection, otherwise the content will not refreshed. I have also faces the same issue in my app.

Comment: @PrakashP I am using 'react-router' like so: import {Route, Router, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router'; 

On each route would I need to add the browser history prop?

Comment: You need to create an object for history and pass to all routes like
<Route history={history} ... />

Comment: I have an object for history like so: const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

Comment: syncHistoryWithStore is imported like: import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

Comment: I added that code to each Route and unfortunately no fix.

Comment: Can you please paste your router code here. It ll be more helpfull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160710/discussion-between-filth-and-prakash-p).